# Extending Octopress to use automatic partials

Tags: ruby, jekyll, liquid

So in Octopress, I want to have a folder full of partials that I can easily display in different ways on the site. I want to have a list of partials' titles that link inside a document which has all of the partials included in it.

This is the logic I want to use, but I don't know how to actually implement it in Octopress.

```
class Collection
  attr_accessor :directory, :files

  def new(dir)
    self.files = []
    self.directory = dir
    load_files
  end

  def list(options={})
    # Handle options here
    files
  end

private

  def load_files
    files_in(@directory).each do |file| # Psuedo-code
      f = Jekyll::FileObject.new(file.read) # Also fictional, but I imagine something similar exists
      f.text # Would return the actual content
      f.yaml # Would return a hash of options from the YAML front matter

      files << f
    end
  end
end
```

Then I want to load in the collection of partials:

```
api_methods = Collection.new("api_methods").list(:alphabetical => true, :method_type => "public")
```

In liquid, listing a table of contents:

```
<ul>
{% for partial in api_methods %}
  <li><a href="{% partial.yaml.url %}">{% partial.yaml.name %}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

In liquid, listing the full text:

```
{% for partial in api_methods %}
  <h2>{% partial.yaml.name %}</h2>

  {% partial.text %}
{% endfor %}
```

So that should hopefully give you a basic picture of what I'm trying to do, but I'm at a loss as to how to actually implement this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, this is how I accomplished what I set out to do.

First, I had to knuckle down and read through Jekyll's source code. Once I had a basic idea of how it worked, I could go in and monkey patch certain things.

Basically, Liquid is a very simple template system and you can't transform any data using it. You have to send the data to Liquid in a "payload", which is just a big hash. So if I wanted to transform some data, I would have to do that in Ruby before it got sent to Liquid.

So I made a thing called `PayloadExtension`:

**plugins/site.rb**

```
module Jekyll
  class Site
    alias :old_site_payload :site_payload

    def site_payload
      PayloadExtension.payload(old_site_payload)
    end
  end
end
```

**plugins/payload_extension.rb**

```
module Jekyll
  class PayloadExtension
    extend OctopressFilters

    def self.payload(payload)
      pages = payload['site']['pages']

      # Filter pages by Public API methods category and sort by title

      public_api_methods = category_filter(pages, "Public API methods")
      public_api_methods.sort! {|a, b| a.data['title'] <=> b.data['title'] }
      public_api_methods = pre_render(public_api_methods)

      payload['site']['public_api_methods'] = public_api_methods

      payload
    end

  private

    def self.category_filter(pages, category)
      pages.reject do |page|
        cat = page.data['category']

        !cat || cat.empty? || cat != category || ( cat.is_a?(Array) && !cat.include?(category) )
      end
    end

    def self.pre_render(pages)
      pages.collect do |page|
        content = pre_filter(page.content)
        page.data['rendered'] = Liquid::Template.parse(content).render
        page
      end
    end

  end
end
```

Unfortunately I wasn't able to mess with `Convertible#do_layout`, so the data I have access to at this stage isn't the final stuff, but that's okay because it's easy to work around.

I also had to manually render the contents of pages myself, because just putting `{{ page.content }}` will spit out text that hasn't been fully parsed.

Now in the actual Liquid templates, I can do this:

```
{% for page in site.public_api_methods %}
  <h2>{{ page.title }} / {{ page.http_method | upcase }}</h2>
  {{ page.rendered }}
{% endfor %}

<h3>Public methods</h3>
<ul>
  {% for page in site.public_api_methods %}
    <li><a href="/api/public-methods/#{{ page.title | slugify }}-{{ page.http_method }}">{{ page.title }}</a></li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```